# Changing email submission notification

Tags: ee2, email

Not sure where to look to make changes to the layout(css) of the email notification submission portion. I have been searching for the View or the module that modifies this. Has anyone made changes to this?

[image: Email Submission]

Comment: The email, or the screen which displays the message you posted above?

Comment: Yes, I have been checking all the error files in the error folder, but none of them appear to be the one. The email.mod does not exactly tell me the redirect address either.

Comment: Which do you want to change - the _email_, or the _message page_?

Comment: The page that says your message has been sent as well any errors. We want to uniform our error pages with our site design.

Answer (score 1):

The only method I see that works is to go to Design, User Messages, and edit everything from there.

Comment: Yes, this is the official way to do this. You might also want to look at [Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages).

Answer (score 0):

[Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) sounds like it would take care of what you need as well as it allows you to serve up your own templates versus editing Design > User Messages.